# Permissions in lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

what kind of permissions must I give or what kind of custom group must I create to achieve the following:

1. Allow members to create new items (workflow is set to start when new item is created)
2. Dont allow members to delete/edit any item on the list
3. Allow selected members to edit lists via tasks they will be
   receiving from a workflow.

We have had problems with users editing list items after having created them and we cant allow that - problem is that if we take out the edit permissions from them the workflow can edit the list with their input from tasks.

I can not have the workflow impersonating someone else with permissions because the process requires to keep track of WHO answered each tasks - impersonating will have all tasks as being answered by me.

Answer (score 0):

The impersonation step is actually still your answer here. The impersonation step allows the workflow to change permissions on the list item.

Here's a high-level example:

List Item: ABC
Preparer: John Doe
Reviewer: Jane Doe
Approver: Billy Bob

Workflow:

- Create new List Item and add users to the appropriate roles
- Workflow beings
- Initiate task creation
- (Impersonation step) Assign task to "current item" variable: Preparer
- Preparer, John Doe, completes and submits task
- (Impersonation step) Assign task to "current item" varaiable: Reviewer
- Reviewer, Jane Doe, complete and submits task
- (Impersonation step) Assign task to "current item" variable: Approver
- Approver, Billy Bob, completes and submits task

The impersonation step is just allowing the item to be reassigned, you need to make your user types a variable and reassign that way.

Comment: A task can have multiple people assigned, thats why I need to know who responded. Is it still possible this way?

Comment: Can you please clarify....are you saying that you may have multiple users listed as a "preparer" (for example)?

Comment: Yes, multiple users listed as preparer, I need to catch who replied to a task

Comment: When you are assigning who the preparers are, allow multiple selections from the people lookup. Then it will automatically get sent to all of them, that way whoever catches it and respond will be recorded inherently as they are logged into their account.